# How to export Outlook inbox into CSV/TSV with timestamp

Tags: email, outlook, csv

I understand that I can export my Outlook 2010 inbox into a CSV or a TSV file using File -> Options -> Advanced -> Export that will give me Subject, Body, ToAddress, FromAddress, Importance, Sensitivity, etc. but the emails do not include timestamps and the "Map Custom Fields" menu does not have an option to include it. How can I achieve this? I think timestamps are one of the most important part of what makes up an email and I am surprised that Microsoft has not included this an obvious option when exporting.

Comment: It is incredibly frustrating that Outlook does not preserve the timestamp when you export. I have no idea why they decided to omit that.